# Doing more than just user+password protection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the standard auth method, which works great to keep people who are not logged in out of my "/my" controller. Here's my code for that:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('my', array('as' => 'my', 'uses' => 'MyController@getIndex'));
});
```

But, now lets say I want to make sure they're logged in AND have activated set to 1 instead of 0. How do I add that rule to this code to make the controller protected from both guests AND logged in users that aren't set to active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to modify your `auth` filter, just add a new one

```
Route::filter('authActive', function()
{
    if (!Auth::user()->active) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

And add the filter to your route group's `before`, after your standard `auth` (separated by a pipe):

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|authActive'), function(){
    Route::get('my', array('as' => 'my', 'uses' => 'MyController@getIndex'));
});
```

A benefit of having two separate filters for this would be that if it passes `auth`, but not `authActive`, you could send them to a different view with an option to re-send an activation email.

Comment: Where would I make that authActive filter? I've been following a guide and it doesn't say anything about that. Is 'auth' a default available filter?

Comment: Yep, `auth` is a default filter.  You should have a `app/filters.php` file  which is where your `auth` filter lives.  You can add the `authActive` filter anywhere in that file.